# Python 3 OOP Calling Methods

Tags: python, algorithm, oop, methods, quicksort

My goal is to implement an algorithm with 3 variations. I decided to create 3 sepearate functions and call them in my 4th function according to what action I want. However, I realised that, performing the task that way I will have 6 functions, 3 with initial actions and 3 calling each action and performing specific tasks (the tasks are the same).

I decided to implement my solution in Python to get used to it, and I was thinking if it is a good idea to use classes and methods. So far every solution for me was just definitions of functions, but I want to improve.

Here is what is my logic so far (showing only declaration which actually confuses me):

```
class InitialAction:
  def __init__(self, a, b):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
  @staticmethod
  def f1(a, b):
    ...
  @staticmethod
  def f2(a, b):
    ...
  @staticmethod
  def f3(a, b):
    ...

class Implement(self, a, b):
  def __init__(self, a, b):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b

  def f4_1(?)
    some_how_call_f1??
    ...
  def f4_2(?)
    some_how_call_f2??
  def f4_3(?)
    some_how_call_f3??
```

And also I am not sure if there is more efficient way than using (a, b) in every method of the {class InitialAction} since they are the same.

Comment: What is your *question*?

Comment: Do `f4_1`, `f4_2`, and `f4_3` differ in any way *other* than which of `f1`, `f2`, or `f3` gets called? If not, you only need one `f4` that takes a function as an argument.

Comment: Also, a class with nothing but static methods doesn't need an `__init__`, because the static methods don't use the attributes. Unlike Java, you don't *have* to use a class if you don't need to; there is nothing wrong with a solution that consists of nothing but definitions, and in fact that's something to *strive* for in many cases.

Comment: Q1: How to call the methods from class InitialAction inside the methods in Implement?
Q2: Should I use (a,b) every time in method definitions inside the classes?

Comment: Answer to @chepner, no matter which method is used, the actions in f4 are going to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

First, a class-based approach, though it doesn't seem warranted.

```
class InitialAction:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def f1(self):
        ...

    def f2(self):
        ...

    def f3(self):
        ...


def f4(f, a, b):
    ...

x = InitialAction(some_a, some_b)

f4(x.f1)  # Implement f4 using f1
f4(x.f2)  # Implement f4 using f2
f4(x.f3)  # Implement f4 using f3
```

The reason you don't really need `InitialAction` is because all it does is hold values of `a` and `b` that you could simply pass directly to `f4` yourself. Instead, just define all four function separately, and `f4`'s body will use `f` as appropriate when the time comes.

```
def f1(a, b):
    ...

def f2(a, b):
    ...

def f3(a, b):
    ...

def f4(f, a, b):
    # Pass a and b to f when appropriate
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no reason to create another class with three methods that have no functionality other than to call the methods defined in the first class.

Assuming you actually just want a wrapper around them, the following would work:

```
class InitialAction:
  @staticmethod
  def f1(a, b):
    ...
  @staticmethod
  def f2(a, b):
    ...
  @staticmethod
  def f3(a, b):
    ...

class Implement(object):
  def __init__(self, a, b):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b

  def callFn(self, fn):
      ...
      fn(self.a, self.b)
      ...

myobj = Implement('a', 'b')
myobj.callFn(InitialAction.f1)
```